# Critical error on mailgun plugin on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, mailgun

Trying to setup mailgun in wordpress with mailgun plugin.
Installs fine but the 'mailgun lists' settings section shows:
*"There has been a critical error on this website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions."*

```
Error:

#0 /home/runcloud/webapps/example/wp-content/plugins/mailgun/mailgun.php(241): Mailgun->api_call()
Stack trace:
2021/03/29 22:59:07 [error] 266087#266087: *179493 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mg_api_get_region() in /home/runcloud/webapps/example/wp-content/plugins/mailgun/mailgun.php:188

2021/03/29 22:58:18 [error] 266087#266087: *179488 access forbidden by rule, client: 158.801.119.239, server: _, request: "GET /.env HTTP/1.1", host: "159.203.922.254"

2021/03/29 22:35:56 [error] 266087#266087: *179452 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  escapeshellcmd() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/runcloud/webapps/example/wp-includes/PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php on line 1779" while reading response header from upstream, client: 262.258.622.926, server: _, request: "POST /wp-login.php?action=lostpassword HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/example.sock:", host: "example.net", referrer: "https://example.net/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword"
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Those are 3 separate, unrelated errors (note the timestamps). Only the last is relevant to your Mailgun problem.  Googling the error doesn't turn up anything useful ... *Installs fine* - how did you install it, and are you 100% sure that worked OK?  Can you review the files on disk and verify, maybe try manually re-insalling?

Comment: I installed directly in WordPress and also manually. Same error.  The install doesn't show any errors. The settings page shows correctly and I am able to change and save settings (including API Keys).